# np.polyfit(x, y, 1) - TypeError: must be str, not float

Tags: python, error-handling, trendline

I have the following dataframe:

[image: df]

`_time` is on the x-axis and `IdCount` is y-axis.

```
x = df['_time']

y = df['IdCount']
```

I would like to compute/draw a trend line by using the code I found here: [How can I draw scatter trend line on matplot? Python-Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635448/how-can-i-draw-scatter-trend-line-on-matplot-python-pandas/41635626)

Therefore, I executed this code:

```
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

and got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-daf6514571b0> in <module>()
----> 1 z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

<__array_function__ internals> in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    590     """
    591     order = int(deg) + 1
--> 592     x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0
    593     y = NX.asarray(y) + 0.0
    594 

TypeError: must be str, not float
```

What do I have to change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type of the `_time` column? I suspect it is a string instead of a `datetime`. Convert it to datetime like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134716/convert-dataframe-column-type-from-string-to-datetime-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: Ok, thanks! But after this I got: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'`.