# plan a method to compare trends of 2 data sets

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-analysis

I would like to get any advice on how to solve the next Data analysis problem with python (pandas matplotlib and seaborn).
I'm working in a chemical plant as an engineer, and I would like to compare data sets ( like temperature, pressure concentration, and so on) in 2 different time frames. The first data frame represents a normal condition, and the second represents a sudden failure.
For example, i have 2 excel files with identical columns parameter names ( pressure, density, temperature, and so on) and the value of the parameters from date x to date y.

What is the best way (with pandas and visualization) to compare the parameter trends between the 2 data frames?

I think to make a boxplot (y= parameter, x= data frame( normal condition and failure condition) ) and then to see if there is any difference.
but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about trends, I don't think a boxplot is a good option. Take a look at this answer: [How can I draw scatter trend line on matplot? Python-Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635448/how-can-i-draw-scatter-trend-line-on-matplot-python-pandas)