# How to make scatterplot from table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I have multiple dataframes as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfA={"1":np.random.rand(3)}
dfA=pd.DataFrame(dfA)
dfB={"2":np.random.rand(5)}
dfB=pd.DataFrame(dfB)
dfC={"3":np.random.rand(6)}
dfC=pd.DataFrame(dfC)
```

and want to combine them like below.

```
dfABC=pd.concat([dfA,dfB,dfC], join="outer")
print (dfABC)
```

For example, dfABC would be like this. (I am not sure why "print" does not work. So let me attach the figure.)

[image]

The expected output will be like this.

[image]

Then I want to make a scatter plot for this table.
X-axis values are 1,2,3.
Y-axis values are dfA(when x=1), dfB(when x=2), and dfC(when x=3).
Is there a function to make scatterplot from this table?
I googled it but could not find it.

Also, it it possible to add trendline?
In the Excel, this scatterplot is easy but I want to use python because actual dataset is quite large.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Not clear on the expected output... do you want 3 subplots for each dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please see the attached figure.

Comment: First, concatenate: `dfABC = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], join="outer", sort=True, axis=1)`. Then, melt and plot: `dfABC.melt().astype(float).plot.scatter('variable', 'value')` you can take it from there.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! Do you happen to know how to add the trendline?

Comment: Perhaps this might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447191/how-to-add-trendline-in-python-matplotlib-dot-scatter-graphs

Answer (score 0):

if i understand, the following could be a good solution for you:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfA={"1":np.random.rand(3)}
dfA=pd.DataFrame(dfA)
dfB={"2":np.random.rand(5)}
dfB=pd.DataFrame(dfB)
dfC={"3":np.random.rand(6)}
dfC=pd.DataFrame(dfC)

dfABC=pd.concat([dfA,dfB,dfC], join="outer")
print (dfABC)

for y in dfABC.columns:
    plt.scatter(dfABC[y].values, dfABC[y])
plt.show()
```