# How to find trend in data set with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, curve-fitting, curve, trend

I am trying to find the curve equation that is the nearest approximation of the trend in the data. I have tried with curve fit, poly1d but none of them give the results I am looking for.

[image]

On the picture, the scatter part is the data that I have. The freehand drawn line is the trend that I would like to get.

Can someone please help me? How can I attempt to get to the solution or at least guide me to the right algorithms that can get me there?

I uploaded the data to the git; x and y dataset files.

https://github.com/tadejales/stackoverflow_question.git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add trendline in python matplotlib dot (scatter) graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447191/how-to-add-trendline-in-python-matplotlib-dot-scatter-graphs)

Comment: Looks maybe like a power law. Perhaps plotting your data with a log-log would help

Comment: @doliphin No it does not. It gives same result as scipy.curve_fit. Or at least I do not know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using ready-made softwares often it is of interest to have a short inspection of the problem. In the present case the shape of the cloud of points makes think of drawing it in log-log scales :

[image]

Then from this rough fitting one obtains :

[image]

Now one can use a specialised software if a better result is expected. The above function and rough numerical values of parameters will be usefull to start the calculus.